# Need suggestion regarding SCORM compliant leaning solutions

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

We are building an m-learning solution[IOS and Android compatible] at our company. The product needs to be SCORM compliant. I would like to know whether it should be developed in-house by the developers or other paid options should be pursued? What are other ways of making our product SCORM compliant? We are not rally positive about using SCORM Engine for this due to its high cost solution to our problem here.Any suggestion/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include SCORM within content using a number of open source options available on GitHub.

Getting SCORM in the content (free) is step 1.
Packaging, bundling and deploying is really step 2.

This typically has a close relationship to how Curriculum defines a structure of lessons, modules, units etc.  Not knowing exactly how they want to organize this, I can speculate that you may just have a simple "I want to know that the student viewed the content" approach.  If you get into a more rich dependency on how the student performs dictating what they see or do next, that requires a much for up front design so you can bridge the design, development, and deployment of your content.

#### Including SCORM Support in content -

Like mentioned if you search google for my [SCOBot](https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot) project or [Pipwerks](https://github.com/pipwerks/scorm-api-wrapper) you'll hit the ground running.
Requires JavaScript friendly developer and some base SCORM knowledge attained thru reading.  This could be outsourced.
Knowing the version of SCORM you wish to support can help.  Consult the LMS to find out that info.

Far as presenting / creating content; if you are doing this from scratch you'd need a HTML/JS developer or if its more interactive your dipping into WebGL, Canvas or beyond.  There are other paid services like iSpring, Captivate and others that offer content creation with SCORM Standards support.  They may even take care of the packaging for you (covered below).

#### Packaging -

This requires a zip (CAM content aggregated model) which includes a imsmanifest.xml file to describe a one to many relationship of a TOC.  Again simple is 1, many begins to allow you to group tiers and add objectives and other things increasing complexity but doable.
You can perform creating this package with XML, Zip and specification knowledge.  I have a Packaging app on my site and a Mac (free) applescript which can also perform very basic packaging.  I am not away of any other free options.

#### Deployment

Commonly performed thru FTP/FileShare by uploading these CAM (zip) packages.  LMS decompresses and reads the manifest.  Sometimes you can just copy the raw files up to the LMS thru a media / content server but this greatly depends on the options.

Comment: That was really helpful. Thanks, @Mark!